# GUI, JComboBox and opening a new window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I am new to Java and especially new to GUI and it's super confusing to me right now.

I'm making a program for class that is supposed to have a menu (JComboBox I'm assuming) that opens a new window when an option is selected.  I am just working on the first option where you click "The Matrix" and a new window pops up with two buttons called "Red Pill" & "Blue Pill" and thats where I've hit a wall.

**I got to the point where I am able to create a new window (not sure if this is even the right route to take for opening the new window) but, When I try to add Buttons to the new pop up window nothing shows up...**.

Thanks for any help or pointers in the right direction!

```
public class MultiForm extends JFrame{

    private JComboBox menu;
    private JButton bluePill;
    private JButton redPill;

private static String[] fileName = {"", "The Matrix", "Another Option"};

public MultiForm() {
    super("Multi Form Program");        
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    menu = new JComboBox(fileName);
    add(menu);

    TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
    menu.addActionListener(handler);        
}

private class TheHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {        
      ********************************************************************  
            //Create a new window when "The Matrix" is clicked in the JCB
            JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            newFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            newFrame.setSize(500, 300);
            newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            Icon bp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Blue Pill.png"));
            bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill", bp);
            newFrame.add(bluePill); 

            Icon rp = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Red Pill.png"));
            redPill = new JButton("Red Pill", rp);
            newFrame.add(redPill);  

            add(panel);
            newFrame.setVisible(true);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MultiForm go = new MultiForm();
    go.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    go.setSize(400, 200);
    go.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the buttons to the new frame? Cause you aren't doing `newFrame.add(...)`. You do not need an extra panel, as the JFrame comes with its own (called the content pane). You should also setVisible *after* you add the components. And rather than manually sizing the frame, you can call `frame.pack()` after adding components, and it'll size the frame to fit the components.

Comment: Yes sorry, I am trying to add it to the newFrame.  Honestly I tried doing newFrame.add(BluePill) and it created a button that was the size of the entire window and it would not allow me to add both buttons that way so I figured that wasn't the correct way.

Comment: *"I tried doing newFrame.add(BluePill) and it created a button that was the size of the entire window and it would not allow me to add both buttons that way"* - That's because the frame uses a `BorderLayout` by default, *"so I figured that wasn't the correct way"* - It's the right approach, you just need to use a layout manager which can accommodate more components or change the position which you are adding the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried doing newFrame.add(BluePill) and it created a button that was the size of the entire window and it would not allow me to add both buttons that way

That's because the frame uses a `BorderLayout` by default.  Unless you specify otherwise, the component's will be added to the `CENTER` position, BUT, `BorderLayout` will only allow a single component to be managed at each of the it's five available positions, so you are only seeing the last component you added.

See [How to Use BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more details

> so I figured that wasn't the correct way

It's the right approach, you just need to use a layout manager which can accommodate more components or change the position which you are adding the buttons

In this little example, I've just use a `FlowLayout`, but you can use what ever is going to give you the effect you desire

```
JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
newFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill");
newFrame.add(bluePill);
redPill = new JButton("Red Pill");
newFrame.add(redPill);

newFrame.pack();
newFrame.setVisible(true);
```

As a general rule of thumb, I don't like adding components like this directly to a top level container, I prefer to use a intermediate container, like a `JPanel`, this gives me more possibilities for re-use, but that's me.

You should also only make the frame visible when it's actually ready, otherwise you may find that some times, the components won't show up

See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer!  I updated my code above before I saw your answer and it's essentially the same except I added the panel and you did newFrame.pack()....What is pack()?

Comment: `pack` calculates the preferred size of the content and wraps the frame around it, taking into consideration the frame borders, so that the content is (as best as possible) always visible...no more guess work

Comment: Oh ok, gotcha!  So I was wrong again I didn't need to add the panel.  If I add text to the top of the newFrame will I then need to add the panel because I'll need to state where everything goes at that point?

Comment: If you're still using the `BorderLayout` of the `JFrame`, you can add (for example) a `JLabel` to the `NORTH` position and a `JPanel` to the `CENTER` position.

Comment: I promise this is the last question.  I added a JLabel, but its a paragraph long and it's all on one line.  How do I format text for a JLabel so that it's not all on one line?

Comment: You can try wrapping the text between `<html>...</html>`, that "might" work.  If it doesn't, you could "fake" it using a `JTextArea`, but you'll need to make it non-editable, remove the border and background (probably making it transparent) and enabling word/line wrapping :P

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the `getContentPane()` method from the new `JFrame`.

You have to actually use `getContentPane()` first because you're not adding any component to the `JFrame` itself but to an intermediate "panel".

```
        JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        newFrame.setSize(300, 200);
        newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill");
        panel.add(bluePill);
        redPill = new JButton("Red Pill");
        panel.add(redPill);

        newFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        newFrame.setVisible(true);
```

You'll have to add a `Layout` to the `JPanel` or/and the `JFrame` and play with the sizes of the component but with this you're on the right path.

I always put the setVisible method a the end, after adding all the components to the frame.

Comment: Got it!  This is probably a stupid question but what is getContentPane and why do I need to add(panel) to it?

Comment: Last question to add a new window to the second option I can do the same thing with creating a new Frame right?  and then could I do a conditional  if(event.getSource() == "The Matrix") then add all the stuff above in that conditional?  If that even works is that the correct route to take?

Comment: @user3862586 Well, using a JFrame, you do not use the add but the getContentPane().add method because you're not adding to the frame but to an intermediate pane on it.

Comment: @user3862586 I would use a, say for example, MatrixListener and implement the ActionListener interface so I'd be sure it is only Matrix that uses it and nothing else. PS : Do not forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Actually, you don't "have" to use `getContentPane`, as of Java 1.5, you can just use `add` (on the `JFrame`) and it will be delegated to the `contentPane` automatically ;)

Comment: Any idea why it wasn't working without the getContentPane?

Comment: Yes sir you are 100% correct!  So I just needed to add it too the panel?  Actually It looks like I just needed to add the panel...I updated my code above based on what you said.

Answer (score 0):

You made some mistakes.

```
add(bluePill);
```

will not do what you want, even if it would, it would still be wrong.
(sounds weird, but I'll explain it)

First the "right" way to do it:

```
//Create a new window when "The Matrix" is clicked in the JCB
        JFrame newFrame = new JFrame();        
        newFrame.setSize(300, 200);
        newFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(newFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        bluePill = new JButton("Blue Pill");
        newFrame.getContentPane().add(bluePill);
        redPill = new JButton("Red Pill");
        newFrame.getContentPane().add(redPill);

        newFrame.setVisible(true);
```

Notice I added "newFrame", because you were calling the method of MultiForm. 
That's because "add()" is the same as "this.add()" and "this" points to MultiForm. Check it with this line if you want:

```
System.out.println(this.toString());
```

The "getContentPane()" is best explained with this image:

[image: JFrame]

You were adding it directly to the JFrame (I don't even know what exactly happens then).

It is also good practice to set the frame visible when it is ready to be visible. Your frame did not contain anything when you made it visible.

Now to the JPanel. A JPanel can hold some elements like JButton,etc. and it can also have a layout. Since you didn't use the JPanel at all, i removed the line from your code. You can still add the JPanel to your ContentPane and add a Layout to the JPanel. (You can also add JPanels to JPanels to create complex layouts)

I hope this was clear for you.

Comment: Yes that cleared up a ton!!  Shit guys, you both answered my questions who do I click the check mark for???

Comment: What is the better way to do it....Skynet you said newFrame.getContentPane().add(bluePill);   and YassinHH you said newFrame.getContentPane().add(panel);

Comment: @user3862586 You'll see that adding a JButton directly to a JFrame content pane will give an unexpected result as the button will take all the place it can. This is due to the BorderLayout by default active on JFrame.

Comment: In answer to your question absolutely nothing shows up when I added it directly to the JFrame.  FYI, the last to sentences about JPanel kinda hurt my head, GUI is so confusing!  lol

Comment: They are both the same, one adds a panel, one adds a button. I always like to keep my elements "grouped" together in a panel. Just experiment a bit with layouts and panels and you should get an idea how this works. You can find some really nice tutorials for swing components here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html

Comment: @user3862586 using a JPanel will make your life easier but you'll have to be familiar with Layouts. Why didn't you accept my answer instead if this one doesn't work for you?

Comment: I honestly didn't know which one to except....They both worked but I excepted Skynets because I had to do newFrame.getContentPane().add(panel.add(bluePill) and the same for redPill to get it to work for both buttons with the panel.  I honestly wish I could except both because I feel like an ass not excepting one, this is the only question where two people answered at relatively the same time with solutions that both worked.